# how to continue the flow when an element is not exists in the execution step

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a div section which loads a accounts data in a table (code snippet below). For some users it loads this whole section, for some users the whole div section does not even present in the screen. So when I wait for this section in general with selenium wait, it works well when a logged in user has any accounts as so it waits for it to load and do the action. But for user who does not have any accounts, the section will not be available and so my script waits for 30 secs and through exception. How can I have a general check, saying if the user has the section, then do action on that section. If not (for different users), without exception, continue with next steps. any help on this please?

[image]

Code snippet

```
<div class="Container savings-dashboard container">
    <div class="py--3">
        <table class="Table2" id="savings-accounts-table" role="grid">
            <tbody class="Table2__body">
                <tr class="Table2Row Table2Row--cta" role="row">
                    <td> </td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

the selenium wait code

```
if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".Container.savings-dashboard.container .Table2")).size() < 1) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceofElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".Container.savings-dashboard.container .Table2")));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such situations I use the following method:

```
public boolean waitForElementPresence(By element, int delay) {
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, delay);
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceofElementLocated(element));
        return true;
    }catch (Throwable t) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here you can pass the element locator and the timeout to wait for that element presence. If normally we use 20-30 seconds timeout here we just wish to validate the element presence so 2-8 seconds will be normally enough.
Also you can pass the XPath String instead of `By` as well.

Comment: yes, I too thought the exact `try, catch` approach. but just thought of checking if there would be any other way. but got the same answer. let me take it anyway. thank you for your help.